# Op Amp not providing sufficient gain

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am building an Affordable Solar Radio Telescope and for it I need an amplifier. I have built the circuit described in pg 8 of this [link](http://www.ncra.tifr.res.in/rpl/Pages/affordable-small-radio-telescope/asrt.pdf).

I have built the exact circuit but I am using a dual supply of 12 V (because I am using op amp IC 741 and read that it works on dual supply).

But the op amp is providing negligible gain, and even though my input is positive. And I am using non inverting mode my output is negative.

What to do?

Comment: The op-amp circuit should give about zero V out for 0V in (+/- a few tens of mV), since the gain is +11. However, if you leave the non- inverting input open , the output will go to about -11V because it needs about 80nA flowing into the input to hold it at 0V,

Comment: Oh my. People need to stop using the '741.

Comment: Eh. At least the 741 has a nice characteristic failure mode. Some other, "better" op amps have a bias which can be of either polarity, and that makes the problem less obvious.

Comment: It's a very old, very expensive amp with poor parameters that people use only because that's what was in the figures in their circuits text.

Answer (score 2):

Spehro's comment is almost certainly correct. Here is how you can check:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQI3Tz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Add R3 and R4 to your circuit, and the two voltages shown should match. Next, short R4 with a clip lead or a piece of wire, and the output should go to zero.

If it works in both cases, you're in business.